# Export tasks with Comments from Asana

Tags: asana, asana-api, asana-connect

I want to export all the details from Asana i.e all workspaces, its projects and all tasks along with the **comments**. I tried exporting in Asana but I could only get the tasks without comments.

Is there any way we can export all the tasks with the comments either through Asana developer APIs or any other third party tools/modules available?

Answer (score 1):

[Full disclosure: I work at Asana :-)]

First off, there's a full-workspace export feature for premium organizations (https://asana.com/guide/help/faq/security#sts=Export)

But assuming you're looking for programming help (which is what stackoverflow is for), check out the documentation of the API, especially the documentation on [comments aka stories](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/stories). You can fetch the comment thread for a task, but it will obviously take a while to make all the calls if you have many tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bridge24.com/asana   This product allows you to connect your asana account and see all your tasks and export them to Excel. In the exported file, you have a sheet for the tasks and also a sheet for the comments.